# EditText contents not getting wraped

Tags: android, android-edittext, word-wrap

Hi I have the following code

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="2000"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
     />
```

The above code doesn't wrap the text to next line it displays the text in full single line and types it in single line can anyone help me.

The above code is inside a linearlayout of a fragment

Comment: Try for "Multiline" option for edittext..

Comment: i have used textMultiLine as inputtype

Comment: i have programmatically set the inputtype now and its working can anyone tell whats the reason?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLength="2000"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:singleLine="false"
     />
```

It will help you...